# Jquery won't replace text in textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery

I don't know why code in the second if loop is not working. It should check string of text area for "[" char and replace it.

```
$(function() {
  $('#form').on('submit',function(){
  if ($('#pzad').is(':checked')){
    var text = $('#mytextarea').val();
    if (text.indexOf('[')>-1 || text.indexOf(']')>-1 ){
        $('#mytextarea').val().replace('[','');
        $('#mytextarea').val().replace('[','');
    }
    $('#mytextarea').val('['+$('#mytextarea').val()+']');
  }});
});
```

Comment: It is working, just differently than you think. replace does not alter the original string, but _returns_ the changed value, so you need to do something with that return value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `.replace()` returns new string, You need to update the `textarea` text.

```
var newstr = $('#mytextarea').val().replace('[','');
$('#mytextarea').val(newstr);
```

You can use [`.val(fn)`](http://api.jquery.com/val/#val-function)

```
$('#mytextarea').val(function(_,currentValue){
    return currentValue.replace('[','');
});
```